# Jade syntax about multiple line string in pre tag

Tags: html, pug

I have Jade code like this:

```
pre='<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\nfoo bar\n</html>'
```

and it render like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
foo bar
</html>
```

How can I achieve something like this:

```
pre='<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
    +'<html lang="en">\n'
    +'foo bar\n'
    +'</html>'
```

or like this:

```
pre="""<!DOCTYPE html>\n"""
    """<html lang="en">\n"""
    """foo bar\n"""
    """</html>"""
```

**Update:**
I have tried following code in [jade-syntax-docs](https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/), it **works**!

```
   pre
    | <!DOCTYPE html>
    | <html lang="en">
    | foo bar
    | </html>
```

[image]

But it **not works** in my test website. My website is generated by **express generator**.
It render like this:

[image]

and html is this:

[image]

If jade version matters, this is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-crud",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

By the way, I use `bootstrap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this :

```
pre
| <!DOCTYPE html>
| foo bar
| </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the pipe `|` like you did, but the solution that is more suitable for your problem is appending a dot `.` to the `pre` tag. You can just keep the indentation. The pipe is recommended if you want to do a single line break.

```
pre.
    yo
    this is
    preformatted
    text
```

will output

```
<pre>yo
this is
preformatted
text</pre>
```

[example](http://codepen.io/franzskuffka/pen/GqJQQb)

Comment: Thanks, Franz, but dot sign cannot escape html tag, I have to use pre='<html>'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
-var myHtml='<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
-myHtml+='<html lang="en">\n'
-myHtml+='foo bar\n'
-myHtml+='</html>'
pre=myHtml
```

Or this :

```
-var myHtml='<!DOCTYPE html>\n'+
- '<html lang="en">\n'+
- 'foo bar\n'+
- '</html>'
pre=myHtml
```

Comment: Thanks, but maybe there are better solution.

Comment: You're welcome, you can also use pipes (|) as shown in the other answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

This could be another solution by the way :

```
-
  var myHtml='<!DOCTYPE html>\n'+
  '<html lang="en">\n'+
  'foo bar\n'+
  '</html>'

pre=myHtml
```